# Creating Global Dynamo table through Pulumi

Tags: typescript, pulumi

From the pulumi [docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/dynamodb/globaltable/) for creating a global dynamo table, creating the global table depends on the replica tables being created first. My Pulumi project is in an asynchronous typescript environment, and I'm creating the replica tables inside the function below.

```js
const replicaTables: any[] = [];
pulumi
  .all([createAwsProvidersInAllRegions(accountsConfig)])
  .apply(async ([providers]) => {
    return providers.map(({ provider, regionName, vpcId, subnets }) => { 
      // create replica tables here
      const regionalReplicaTable = createReplicaTable();
      replicaTables.push(regionalReplicaTable);

   });
});
```

I'm trying to create the global table in the code below.

```js
 new aws.dynamodb.GlobalTable(`${namespace}-deviceInfo-global`, {replicas: replicaTables},
  {
     dependsOn: replicaTables,
  },
```

But the `replicaTables` array is empty at the time this code runs due to the asynchronous nature of the node environment. How do I ensure that the `replicaTables` array is filled with the replica tables at the time the code to create the global table runs?

Comment: Is `accountsConfig` an output? Why does it have to be inside `pulumi.all`?

Comment: `accountsConfig` is not a Pulumi outout, but it's an array of Pulumi configs.
`const accountsConfig = config.requireObject<AccountConfig[]>('awsAccounts');`

Comment: Then I wouldn't put it inside an apply. Use a loop or an `Array.map` to create replicas?

Comment: don't I still need a container to hold all replicas even if I extract creating the replicas out of the `pulumi.all`? I'm still unsure what the point of `pulumi.all()` is.